# Flex 4 : change element position in a s:List

Tags: apache-flex, list, actionscript, adobe

I have a s:List in my flex application attached to an ArrayCollection ( elements ).
I want to change position of one element, so in fact I'm changing it's item index, the question is, how to do this kind of action ?

**Here is a better example :**

item 1   i : 1
item 2   i : 2
item 3   i : 3
item 4   i : 4

i = index

Inside the item there is a button named " Up ", when i'm cliking on it on the item 3 for example, it's becoming like this :

item 1  i : 1
item 3  i : 2
item 2  i : 3 
item 4  i : 4

So as we can see, we have a new index for the item 3...

How can I achieve this in actionscript and see that the item moved in the interface.

Thx !

Comment: I don't know why you don't post details of what you tried. This question looks like you are trying to get others to do your work for you. Read the [faq], such questions are NOT appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In the above answer,by Setting the selectedItem of list to the Selected Obj instead of setting the selectedIndex of the List to newPos,we donot need to change or maintain any selection in ArrayCollection explicitly.

public function moveUp(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var index:Number = myList.selectedIndex;

```
            if (index > 0) {                
                var obj:Object = elements.getItemAt(index);
                var newPos:Number = index - 1;

                elements.removeItemAt(index);
                elements.addItemAt(obj, newPos);

                myList.selectItem = obj; (instead of myList.selectedIndex = newPos;)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should have done when you saw an `ArrayCollection` is attached is seen the [DOCUMENTATION](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html)

You would have seen that it has methods like `addItemAt` and `removeItemAt`

So the obvious thing to do would be:

```
private function moveUp(collection:ArrayCollection, indexToMove:int, numPlaces:int=1) {
    var newIndex:int = indexToMove - numPlaces;
    if(newIndex < 0) {
        newIndex = 0;
    }
    var itemToMove:Object = collection.removeItemAt(indexToMove);
    collection.addItemAt(itemToMove, newIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your ArrayCollection is binded to your list, I would alter the arrayCollection directly like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var elements:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {label : "item 1"},
                {label : "item 2"}, 
                {label : "item 3"}, 
                {label : "item 4"} 
            ]);

            public function moveUp(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var index:Number = myList.selectedIndex;

                if (index > 0) {                
                    var obj:Object = elements.getItemAt(index);
                    var newPos:Number = index - 1;

                    elements.removeItemAt(index);
                    elements.addItemAt(obj, newPos);

                    myList.selectedIndex = newPos;
                }
            }


            public function moveDown(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var index:Number = myList.selectedIndex;

                if (index < elements.length - 1) {
                    var obj:Object = elements.getItemAt(index);
                    var newPos:Number = index + 1;

                    elements.removeItemAt(index);
                    elements.addItemAt(obj, newPos);

                    myList.selectedIndex = newPos;
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:List id="myList" labelField="label" dataProvider="{elements}"/>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button label="Move up" click="moveUp(event)"/>
        <s:Button label="Move down" click="moveDown(event)"/>
    </s:HGroup>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Now, up to you to apply the same logic from within your custom list item renderer using either a call to a parent function, or a custom event. Good luck!